# When plotting specific column of a pandas df, jupyter notebook only shows 1 graph per cell. How can I show multiple graphs separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
%matplotlib inline

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']= (20, 10)
df_1['col1'].plot(kind='bar')
df_2['col1'].plot(kind='bar')
```

In above code, only the first graph shows up in jupyter notebook.

But if I am plotting entire df then multiple graphs will show in jupyter notebook. eg:

```
df_1.plot(kind='bar')
df_2.plot(kind='bar')
```

I would like to see 2 different figures in the output.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use axes handles:

```
ax = df_1.plot(kind='bar')
_ = df_2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

Example:

```
ax = df_1.plot(kind='bar', alpha = .4)
_ = df_2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, color='green', alpha = .4)
```

[image]